# Javascript object initialized with several functions: what syntax is it?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am reviewing some Javascript code and stumbled upon a syntax that I didn't knew. The application is a React and Redux one, though I think this is plain Javascript.

The syntax I'm concerned with is the `{ f1(), f2(), ... }` argument of `combineReducers()`.

This is the syntax:

```
combineReducers({
  Reducer1,
  Reducer2,
  ...
});
```

ReducerN is a function, i.e.:

```
const Reducer1 = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  // ...
};
```

I get `{ f1(), ... }` creates an object where the function name is the key and the function itself is the value, so in a browser console I tried the following:

```
a = () => { console.log(1) }
b = () => { console.log(2) }
o = {a, b}
```

and if I print `o`:

```
{a: ƒ, b: ƒ}
a: () => { console.log(1) }
b: () => { console.log(2) }
__proto__: Object
```

But if I try to initialize `o` in a single operation:

```
o = { () => return 1 }
```

or

```
o = { function y() { return 1 }}
```

they both give a syntax error.

It's the first time I see an object created with that syntax: What kind is that? Where can I find its reference?

Comment: [Object_initializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer)

Comment: `{Reducer1, Reducer2}` is ES6 shorthand for `{Reducer1: Reducer1, Reducer2: Reducer2}`

Comment: There's nothing special about them being functions, that's something `combineReducers()` deals with.

Comment: for `function y() { return 1 }`, you need to give your key as `a` or `b` as declaring a function won't destructure the function name as a key. therefore `{ a: function () { return 1 } }` should work. PS it would be `() => 1` and not `() => return 1`

Comment: @Barmar Ah, [ES6 shorthand initializers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015) (or a bit more detailed [down that same page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Property_definitions)), thank you. Not easy to spot at first read :-)

Comment: in this `o = { () => return 1 }` or `o = { function y() { return 1 }}`  you are actually trying to create an object and attach a value to it without having a key to that value inside the object, as @Barmar said this is an ES6 syntax to initialize object, you can have your failing example to work like this: `o = { func: function y() { return 1 }}` and it will work.

Comment: @Barmar Can't edit the previous comment, but the exact link is to [ES6 Shorthand method names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Method_definitions).

Comment: @Ma'mounothman Thanks, but the correct version would be `o = { y() { return 1 }}` (see my last comment).

Answer (score 1):

As said previously,

```
combineReducers({
  Reducer1,
  Reducer2,
  ...
});
```

is equivalent to this in plain ES5:

```
combineReducers({
  Reducer1: Reducer1,
  Reducer2: Reducer2,
  ...
});
```

and `combineReducers` is concerned only with the [values of the object passed in](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/master/src/combineReducers.ts#L78). The first form is just a [shorthand](https://javascript.info/object#property-value-shorthand) for defining properties with the same name as the value. This is the reason you cannot use anonymous functions in this form. To define function members on classes and objects, you can use the following form:

```
class Foo {
    foo() { console.log('foo'); }
    bar = () => console.log('bar')
}

const a = new Foo();
a.foo();
a.bar();

const b = {
    foo() { console.log('foo'); }
    bar: () => console.log('bar')
};

b.foo();
b.bar();
```

When transpiling to plain ES5, this will generate the following:

```
"use strict";
var Foo = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Foo() {
        this.bar = function () { return console.log('bar'); };
    }
    Foo.prototype.foo = function () { console.log('foo'); };
    return Foo;
}());

var a = new Foo();
a.foo();
a.bar();

var b = {
    foo: function () { console.log('foo'); },
    bar: function () { return console.log('bar'); }
};

b.foo();
b.bar();
```

Answer (score 0):

`{ f1() }` is very different than `{ f1 }`.

The latter is a shorthand of `{ f1: f1 }` which is an object having the key `'f1'` (a string) associated to the value `f1` (a function). The function is not executed.

In the first example `f1()` is a function call. The function `f1` is executed and the value it returns is used instead. But because you didn't provide a key to associate the value with and because `f1()` is a value that does not have a name (it is an expression that needs to be evaluated in order to get its value), JS cannot produce an object out of it.

`{ f1 }` can be evaluated at the compile time and turned into `{ f1: f1 }`.
`{ f1() }` cannot be evaluated at the compile time. The value of `f1()` is available only at the run time.

This is why `{ f1() }` is invalid code.

If you need to call `f1` and use the value it returns to create an object you can do it this way:

```
const x = { f1: f1() }
```

This is the same thing as:

```
const v = f1();
const x = { f1: v }
```